# LoginView control question!

Tags: c#, asp.net, loginview

I have a button in that control. How do i reach it programmatically.. I cant reach it by pressing the buttons ID in the code partial class code file.

```
          if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrator") || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Moderator"))
        {
            Button button = (Button)LoginView1.FindControl("DeleteThread");
```

Comment: have you found an answer for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t109239-accessing-a-control-within-loginview.html)

> For the LoginView control, when being
>   added onto a page, at a certain time,
>   only one Template (anonymous or
>   loggedIn ) is applied on the Control
>   instance, so at that time, we can only
>   retrieve the reference of those
>   controls in the active template( can't
>   access those in the non-active
>   template). So you can first determine
>   whether the user has been
>   authenticated or not and then use the
>   LoginView.FindControl( stringId)
>   together with the sub control's ID to
>   retrieve the control reference.

Comment: Do you mean. Like the one above?